# Can we achieve one to many insertion using Merge statements in Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

here is the snapshot of what I wanna achive.

[image]

EmployeeReviewType is the Type of sql server.
I want to pass this to sql server stored procedure at once. 
Then I need to insert a record into employee table. Then according to the reviews I need to insert review details in separate table named as tbl_Reviews.

I can achieve this the harder way.

Can I achieve this functionality using merger statements in stored procedures? If yes then How?

Comment: please post expected results and sample results as text

Comment: expected result is in the tbl_Employee And tbl_Reviews